# Reading one source Stream by multiple consumers asynchronously

Tags: c#, concurrency, async-await, stream, .net-core

The problem was using single `Stream` from the HTTP response in multiple consumers simultaneously. For example: while data is loading, I want write it to the some cache file and deserealize it at the same time.

This code will not work for an obvious reason. But it represents some desired things.

```csharp
private readonly HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();

// BAD CODE!!!
private async Task<T> HttpAPIRequest<T>(string url, string path)
{
    using HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(false);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    using Stream responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    using FileStream fileStream = File.Create(path);
    ValueTask<T> jsonTask = JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<T>(responseStream);
    await responseStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
    return await jsonTask;
}
```

---

### The solution

After few days of hard search for the solution I've ended up with the following one consisting of two classes:

```csharp
public sealed class ConcurrentStreamReader : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Stream _inputStream;
    private readonly MemoryStream _memoryStream;
    private readonly int _bufferSize;
    private readonly IProgress<long> _progress;

    public ConcurrentStreamReader(Stream inputStream) : this(inputStream, null) { }

    public ConcurrentStreamReader(Stream inputStream, IProgress<long> progress) : this(inputStream, 81920, 0, progress) { }

    public ConcurrentStreamReader(Stream inputStream, int bufferSize, int capacity, IProgress<long> progress)
    {
        _memoryStream = new MemoryStream(capacity);
        _inputStream = inputStream;
        _bufferSize = bufferSize;
        _progress = progress;
    }

    public Stream CreateNewStream() => new BlockingStream(ReadStream().GetEnumerator(), _memoryStream);

    public async Task CopyToAsync(Stream outputStream)
    {
        foreach (ReadOnlyMemory<byte> buffer in ReadStream())
        {
            await outputStream.WriteAsync(buffer);
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<ReadOnlyMemory<byte>> ReadStream()
    {
        long position = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[_bufferSize];
        int bytesRead;
        while (true)
        {
            if (position == _memoryStream.Length)
            {
                lock (_inputStream)
                {
                    if (position < _memoryStream.Length) continue;
                    bytesRead = _inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, _bufferSize);
                    if (bytesRead == 0) break;
                    lock (_memoryStream)
                    {
                        _memoryStream.Position = _memoryStream.Length;
                        _memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                }
                _progress?.Report(_memoryStream.Length);
            }
            else
            {
                lock (_memoryStream)
                {
                    _memoryStream.Position = position;
                    bytesRead = _memoryStream.Read(buffer, 0, _bufferSize);
                }
            }
            position += bytesRead;
            yield return new ReadOnlyMemory<byte>(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }

    private bool _disposed;
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _memoryStream.Dispose();
            }
        }
        _disposed = true;
    }
    ~ConcurrentStreamReader() => Dispose(false);
}

public sealed class BlockingStream : Stream
{
    private readonly IEnumerator<ReadOnlyMemory<byte>> _sourceEnumerator;
    private readonly MemoryStream _stream;
    private long _position;

    private BlockingStream() { }

    public BlockingStream(IEnumerator<ReadOnlyMemory<byte>> sourceEnumerator, MemoryStream stream)
    {
        _stream = stream;
        _sourceEnumerator = sourceEnumerator;
        _position = 0;
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        long tail = _position + offset + count;
        while (tail >= _stream.Length && _sourceEnumerator.MoveNext()) { }
        int bytesRead;
        lock (_stream)
        {
            _stream.Position = _position;
            bytesRead = _stream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
        }
        _position += bytesRead;
        return bytesRead;
    }

    public override bool CanRead => true;
    public override bool CanSeek => false;
    public override bool CanWrite => false;
    public override long Length => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public override long Position { get => throw new NotSupportedException(); set => throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    public override void Flush() => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin) => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public override void SetLength(long value) => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) => throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

Additionally I've included to the solution the download Progress reporting (that I will not use in the usage example below).

And the usage

```csharp
private async Task<T> HttpAPIRequest<T>(string url, string path)
{
    using HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(false);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    using Stream responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    using ConcurrentStreamReader reader = new ConcurrentStreamReader(responseStream);
    using FileStream fileStream = File.Create(path);
    using Stream deserealizerStream = reader.CreateNewStream();
    ValueTask<T> jsonTask = JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<T>(deserealizerStream);
    await reader.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
    return await jsonTask;
}
```

**Environment:** x64 WPF app / .NET Core 3.1

The code works correctly but it's pretty complicated for me especially near `lock()` statements. I'm not sure of that part and performed some code changes as random fixes while I was testing it. Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered to use `SynchronizedStream` via `Stream.Synchronized`?

Comment: @PeterCsala No, but good point. Thank you very much! Will learn something about it.

Comment: @PeterCsala I've read a lot about [`SynchronizedStream`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/Stream.cs#L1072)  wrapper and it will not help to avoid lock() or make less locks in the code. Thus it's useless for me here. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) as well as  [_what you may and may not do after receiving answers_](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765).

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ Thanks for the warning. I did not update any things that may affect existing answers or comments. Otherwise I'll notify the members of updates. I just solved some bad optimization problems in the code that were not reported neither above nor below.

Comment: @aepot Minor but important observation: You are using `lock` statements on those objects on which you are working on. Your `_inputStream `is locked even though it is received as input. Please use separate lock objects for these. Here you can find some valuable resources about this topic: [1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement), [2](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/lock-statement-best-practices), [3](https://www.tomfosdick.com/archives/90525)

Comment: @PeterCsala You're right but I'm aware of it and was cereful in using locks. I know that it's violates some programming culture and will consider fixing it. Thank you again!

Comment: @aepot I've jut forgot to ask you about memory optimization. Is it a concern for you? Because fortunately there are plenty of good techniques to reduce the memory footprint. Like instead of directly allocating a `byte[]` you could use [ArrayPool](https://adamsitnik.com/Array-Pool/). Instead of directly allocating a `MemoryStream` you could use [RecycableMemoryStream](https://github.com/microsoft/Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream). You could also take advantage of the `PipeReader` \ `SequenceReader` [1](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/an-introduction-to-sequencereader)

Comment: @PeterCsala Yet another Thank you! For now the code looks well-optimized for me. It allocates one `MemoryStream` and not so many `byte[]`s per API request. Another good thing that it doesn't consume more memory for new consumers because `BlockingStream` has no own storage. But I'll definetly look at all listed above classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not need report progress then the [LoadIntoBuffer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent.loadintobufferasync?view=netcore-3.1) [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/aaca53b025f41ab638466b1efe569df314f689ea/System/net/System/Net/Http/HttpContent.cs#L276) + [CopyToAsync](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent.copytoasync?view=netcore-3.1) [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/aaca53b025f41ab638466b1efe569df314f689ea/System/net/System/Net/Http/HttpContent.cs#L276) combo could be handy.

All you need to prevent the concurrent call of the `LoadIntoBuffer` method. (You can call it n times it does not matter, because the `IsBuffered` flag will short-cut the method.) This can be done by using a `Monitor` or a `Semaphore` for mutual exclusion. Or you can simply use signalling primitives as well, like `AutoResetEvent`, `CountdownEvent`.

With `CopyToAsync` each thread can have its own copy of the stream, so there won't be a shared resource.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately progress reporting is required.

Comment: Great thanks for the suggestions! I have no more questions related to my code.